# In Python, how can I print out a board of numbers representing tic-tac-toe, with a "|" in between each number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I want to be able to rewrite the code in as few lines as possible, possibly in list comprehension syntax. Here is what the output should be:

```
1|2|3  
4|5|6  
7|8|9
```

This is what I have thought up. The separator doesn't actually print the "|". Any suggestions?

```
for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
    print(i, sep = "|", end = "")
    if (i) % 3 == 0:
        print()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just print it.

```
>>> print('1|2|3\n4|5|6\n7|8|9')
1|2|3
4|5|6
7|8|9
```

To clarify: Yes, I'm obviously assuming that really exactly these numbers shall be printed. I think it's a reasonable assumption, given that the OP also only showed those numbers both in the desired output and in the code, didn't say anything about more flexibility (really should have if it were required), and **tic-tac-toe has X and O, not numbers**. I suspect this is for showing the user which number to enter for which field during play.

Comment: Didn't downvote :) certainly meets the "as few lines as possible" requirement

Comment: And every other requirement.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> numbers = range(1, 10)

>>> print(('{}|{}|{}\n' * 3).format(*numbers))
1|2|3
4|5|6
7|8|9
```

Comment: small fix to your good solution: print(('{}|{}|{}\n' * 3).format(*range(1,10)).strip('\n')) , it will strip extra new line feed at the end. +1 from my side.

Comment: Yah, I was hoping nobody would notice :-). Or that the OP doesn't care. Alternatively do `print ('{}|{}|{}\n' * 3).format(*range(1, 10)),` in Python 2 or `print(('{}|{}|{}\n' * 3).format(*range(1, 10)), end='')` in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

[I like format the most because it offers the best flexibility:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

```
moves = [' ', ' ',' ',' ', 'x',' ',' ', ' ','o']
board = "|{}|{}|{}|\n|{}|{}|{}|\n|{}|{}|{}|\n"
print(board.format(*moves)
```

Modify the items in that list and run that same print statement for an on-the-go solution.

And there, I managed to slim it down to 3 lines. If I wasn't initializing the list, it would only be 2 lines.

Comment: @cricket_007 -- true enough, but this is an excellent idea nevertheless +1

Comment: You're wrong. What unpacks is the `*` in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest and most elegant way to do it in `python 3` using `print`:

```
for i in 1,4,7:
    print(i,i+1,i+2, sep='|')
```

Or using `range`:

```
for i in range(1,10,3):
    print(*range(i,i+3), sep='|')
```

Also there is a good reading here about iterable unpacking operator: [Additional Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)

Also here is one-liner, not the shortest one but very readable:

```
print('\n'.join(('{}|{}|{}'.format(i,i+1,i+2) for i in (1,4,7))))
```

And original one-liner from `@Stefan Pochmann`'s comment:

```
print(('{}|{}|{}\n' * 3).format(*range(1, 10)), end='')
```

Output for all is the same:

```
1|2|3
4|5|6
7|8|9
```

Comment: No point creating a list, tuple is enough and shorter/simpler/faster.

Comment: Just curious: Do you disagree, or do you not understand what I mean?

Comment: Well, it would save two characters and I think it does look simpler. Just in case it isn't clear, what I mean is `for i in 1,3,7:`, getting rid of those brackets.

Comment: i added the change, so everybody's happy:)

Answer (score 0):

`sep` doesn't work when you only give a single thing to print

```
>>>print(1, sep='|')
1
>>> print(1,2,3, sep='|')
1|2|3
```

---

Could do this instead

```
for i in range(1,10):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print(i, end="\n")
    else:
        print(i, end="|")
```

Shortening to a ternary

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i, end="\n") if i % 3 == 0 else print(i, end="|")
```

Output

```
1|2|3
4|5|6
7|8|9
```

Comment: IMHO this is too much work to print something that will have the same structure each time it is printed.

Comment: @IbrahimAhmed - Two lines is too much work? The rest is just an explanation why it didn't work before

Comment: No, the use of a loop that executes 9 times is. 1 simple print statement is all that is necessary once the structure of the item has been chosen.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the question of "why the separator wasn't printing".

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - Right? Thank you. I didn't understand why I got downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

`print('\n'.join(['|'.join([str(c) for c in s[i:i+3]]) for i in range(0,9,3)]))`

Don't use this (but it works).  This assumes your array is in a variable named `s`

Comment: Why say don't use it? It is fairly natural.

Comment: I just tend to dislike long-ish one liners.  I would probably split it into a couple of lines - but trying to meet the fewest lines possible req ;)

Comment: Is it really necessary to have so much convolution> That's 2 nested loops, and list comprehension. This can be confusing to the python beginners.

Comment: @IbrahimAhmed OP asked for something as short as possible and explicitly mentioned that list comprehension syntax is okay.

Comment: I've got fewest lines... and fewer characters :P

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that is purely the smallest amount of lines, you can use the ternary syntax:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i,end='|\n') if (i) % 3 == 0 else print(i,end = "|")
```

Output:

```
1|2|3
4|5|6
7|8|9
```

Answer (score 0):

If we're going to code golf, lets code golf properly...

One line:

```
print("".join(str(i)+'\n|'[i%3>0]for i in range(1,10)))
```

You can make it one character shorter when you realise that the indexer `>0` is actually longer than repeating the pipe (`|`):

```
print("".join(str(i)+'\n||'[i%3]for i in range(1,10)))
```

This gives:

```
1|2|3
4|5|6
7|8|9
```

If you need even shorter, a `for` loop technically doesn't need to be on a new line, also in Python 3 `print` will print every `*args`, until the `*kwargs`.

```
for i in range(1,10,3):print(i,i+1,i+2,sep='|')
pass # Pass not needed, just shows syntactically how it works.
```

The first line above is probably the shortest you can get, without just printing the string as is.

Comment: first and second examples will add extra newline at the end of output